# Starting sphinxsearch

Tags: services

I've successfully installed sphinxsearch following the documentation here:
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html

When I try running the command `sudo service sphinxsearch start`

It returns the following:

`sphinxsearch stop/pre-start, process 4392`

I'm unable to then find this pid and if I immediately run the same command with stop I get
`stop: Unknown instance:`

I am able to manually start it by running `searchd` however, my test script to search is not returning results like it does in my dev environment. Unsure if this is related or not yet...